# IASK In App Settings Kit - UITabController Multi View

Tags: ios, settings, inappsettingskit

I have created an application that uses a UITabBarController, one of the tabs is 'Settings' for which I am using IASK.

This works fine for most of the settings, however when I use a 'Multi Value' and press the button I am not presented with the next view controller with the relevant multi values.

Is this something to do with the UITabBarController, does IASK want a UINavigationController?

I'm not seeing any errors, the cell I selected just stays greyed and nothing happens.

Any help or tips would be much appreciated!

Thx//56k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, IASK needs to be embedded in a `UINavigationController` since it pushes view controllers on the stack.

Comment: Ah ok.. so you can't use it with a TabBarController? Is there another way that I am missing. TIA.

Comment: Sure you can. Embed a UINavigationController in the UITabBarController. IASK then is the root view controller of the navigation controller.